# Generating Google Spreadsheet hyperlinks from cell contents

Tags: google-sheets, links

I have a column of cells in a Google Spreadsheet with values such as:

```
37683
36583
38637
32391
```

What I would like to do is generate a hyperlink for each cell like:

`http://mywebsite.com?id=xxxxx`

...where xxxxx is the value of the cell. I know the format of a hyperlink in a Google spreadsheet and could do the job manually, I'm just wondering if I can generate these using a simple find/replace, or whether it will need scripting.

The new hyperlink can either go into the original cell, or a new cell can be created.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Assuming your values are in column A, you can do this in column B:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://mywebsite.com?id=",A1);"link text")
```

Then you can auto-fill down the rest of the column.

If you want the text of the link to be the same as the id you're linking, that's as simple as

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://mywebsite.com?id=",A1);A1)
```

Comment: @AlEverett now how do you create that link in the same cell as the value? And keep the value as the text?

Comment: @Kirill: Copy / Paste values

Comment: I realize this question is very old, but current Google Sheets (in 2018) does not create the link unless the URL is a literal string or cell reference. Using a formula to create the URL string will not work. You need to create the URL with a formula in one cell, then use the HYPERLINK function in another cell, referencing the created URL. Cell B1: `="http://mywebsite.com?id=" & A1` Cell C1: `=HYPERLINK(B1, "link text")` or `=HYPERLINK(B1)`

Comment: Works fine for me in 2022.

Comment: Personally, I was able to do this (without needing different text for the link) using just the formula `="http://mywebsite.com?id="&A1` (with or without spaces around the `&`) – well, I was using a different URL fragment and had the relevant IDs in a different column, but the same logic applies. It also works as `=CONCATENATE("http://mywebsite.com?id=",A1)` (again, with or without spaces around the comma). Use whichever format you prefer. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Column A   Column B  Column C
  1    id's      Names
  2   37683      name 1
  3   36583      name 2
  4   38637      name 3
  5   32391      name 4
```

Pasting the below into C1 will generate text (from column B) with hyperlink attached that combines the web address (`http://mywebsite.com?id=`) with the id's (from column A). Change "Column Title" in the formula to whatever you want column C to be named in C1.

={"Column Title";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,(HYPERLINK(("`http://mywebsite.com?id=`"&A2:A),B2:B))))}