# Include Cell Content as Part of Hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets

I have reviewed [other questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31079/84107) which get 'close' but don't quite address my issue.

I have a range of cells like (which we will call A1,A2,A3)

```
Bob
Charlie
Mary
```

within each cell I would like to embed a hyperlink in each cell in that range
which would look something like: =HYPERLINK("http://www.myURL.com/user/" & A1,"Bob") so that the URL effectively becomes http://www.myURL.com/user/bob

This (understandably) creates a 'circular reference'...Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This (understandably) creates a 'circular reference'...Is there anyway
>   around this?

You can get circular references to work by going to `File > Spreadsheet settings > Calculation > Iterative calculation` in your spreadsheet and switching that to "On".

You can also set the number of iterations the circular references will be calculated for. For your case, you might need to set this to 1 or 2 or something like that to get the exact behavior you're looking for.

Comment: It did require a number of iterations = 2 (on the first iteration the result was 0) but after that it worked perfectly. Thanks so much.