# Google Sheets function to create hyperlink based on data in cell, but not if the cell is empty

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

The solution outlined [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/generating-google-spreadsheet-hyperlinks-from-cell-contents) is ideal for my needs (converting an article ID in column C into a hyperlink to a CMS that displays in column D).

However, I would like the formula to leave column D blank if the adjacent cell in column C is blank.

My current function is...

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://WEBSITECMS.COM?post=",C228,"&action=edit"),C228
)
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheets hyperlinks created from data inserted into cell]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap it into IF: if C228 is blank, then remain blank, if it isn't it should create the HYPERLINK:

```
=IF(C228="","",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://WEBSITECMS.COM?post=",C228,"&action=edit"),C228))
```

Comment: Ahh – this is perfect! Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted.

If you can somehow have it retain cell styling (specifically retaining that pink band separating days) I will backflip out of this StackExchange with excitement.

Comment: I don't get what that pink band is and how it's supposed to work